# Demystifying LTA: Monthly Component and Travel Block Limitations

Tags: india, salary, payroll-taxes, payroll

my salary slip shows a monthly **LTA** component, but the block period allows only `2` trips in `4` years (**2022-2025**). Only `1` trip, in a financial year, can be claimed I guess. What does this monthly limit signify, when we can claim only `1` trip and not on month-on-month basis?

1. Does it represent the cumulative amount used until travel, with deduction applicable up to that limit?
2. What happens when you switch jobs, the previously accumulated amount in the previous organization is lapsed and it again starts from `0` even though we are in the same block? Or, does that get carry-forward and can be shown to the current employer?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found a good post [Questions related to leave travel allowance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44750/questions-related-to-leave-travel-allowance?rq=1) answering some questions about LTA, but the monthly part, as in my case, is still not clear. Also, I will wait for answers here in case some rules have been changed recently which am not aware of.